# Preventing multiple getter invoke in a session managed bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, session-variables, getter

i'm using jsf 2.0.2 + richfaces 3.3.3.
what can i do so my getter won't be invoked multiple time ??

i have this:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mybean")
@SessionScoped
public class mybean implements Serializable {        
public MyClass getMyClass() {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getRenderResponse()) {
            myClass = get_it_from_database();
        }
        return myClass;
    }
```

i also used this:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "mybean")
@SessionScoped
public class mybean implements Serializable {        
public MyClass getMyClass() {
        if (myClass = null) {
            myClass = get_it_from_database();
        }
        return myClass;
    }
```

but what i wanted is to "refresh" ONCE my data whenever i refresh the page...

Answer (score 3):

You can't prevent that. That's the nature of a getter. A getter method is intented to **return** data (read: to provide an access point for outside), not to **load** data. There you normally use the bean constructor, `@PostConstruct` or action method for.

To solve your particular problem, redeclare the bean to be request scoped and move the line `myClass = get_it_from_database();` to bean's constructor or a `@PostConstruct` method if it has injected dependencies. Or if you really insist in keeping it session scoped (you should prefer having two beans: one session scoped for session scoped data and one request scoped for request scoped data), then your first approach is the most reasonable.

#### See also:

- [Why JSF calls getters multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0):

make a myclass property with getter setter and return that so on referesh it will be maintained and ha use also null check as mentioned in question. Have a nice day